# mod_rewrite where the rewrite rule matches a directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a mod_rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(alice)/?$ bob.php?page=$1 [L]
```

If I go to http://localhost/alice/, it reads bob.php (as expected). If I go to http://localhost/alice (no end slash), it reads bob.php (again, as expected).

If I create an directory in htdocs called "alice", and go to http://localhost/alice/, it reads bob.php. But, if I go to http://localhost/alice, it now redirects to http://localhost/alice/?page=alice. It still reads bob.php (which is what I want), but I'd rather it wasn't altering the URL like that.

Why is it doing that, and is there any way of preventing it (other than just not having such directories lying about)?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic: I considered posting it there in the first place, but SO has 3716 questions tagged mod-rewrite and SF has only 578. Of course, popularity doesn't make something right, but, in my experience, rewrite rules are a question for programmers rather than sysadmins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be caused by the /? at the end - removing the ? causes (when the alice directory exists):

- /alice to be redirected to /alice/, and displayed as /bob.php?page=alice
- /alice/ to display as /bob.php?page=alice

If the alice directory does not exist, /alice will not be redirected (but /alice/ will be). If you know whether the directory exists or not, you can choose whether to use / or /?.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(alice)/?$ bob.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for your response. However, I do actually want http://localhost/alice to display bob.php, I just don't want it to alter the URL. I've edited my question to clarify this.